# LineChart in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, custom-controls

I havo to implement a custom control in WPF which contains a line chart. This control should permit to an user to define, with a control template, the number of grids, the font family and the font size of axis labels and other parameters.
I'm wondering if one of you can address me to an example or give me some advice.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [CodeProject article with code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/swordfishcharts.aspx) which demonstrates how you can create a line chart in WPF.

It should be fairly easy to adapt it to your requirements.